# Unable to refetch query using 'id' inside onSuccess() callback of useMutation in react-query 3.6.0

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-query

I was using `QueryCache.refetchQueries` to refetch the query with id **'fetchProducts'** but it failed to work.

[image]

Then I saw react-query migrated to version 3.0 with some changes. I saw a refetch query code example `queryClient.invalidateQueries('fetchProducts')` in docs and used it but still, the page needs to be get refreshed to view the latest changes.

[image]

Screenshot of react-devtools:

*(This shows that the query is saved in cache with id **fetchProducts** but unable to refetch after a successful response from mutation)*

[image]

Comment: are you using the "correct" `queryClient` - by that I mean - did you retrieve it via: `const queryClient = useQueryClient()` ?

another thing: Your screenshot literally shows that the query is currently fetching (indicated by the blue 1 and the blue `fetching` badge on the top right), so I think your query might be re-fetching correctly. Maybe it errors or there is a retry and thus it takes longer. Have you checked your network tab for outgoing requests?

Comment: It's only re-fetching the latest items when I'm leaving the browser window and coming back to it.

Comment: That doesn’t answer my question: where is queryClient coming from when you do: `queryClient.invalidateQueries('fetchProducts')`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are manually fetching using the refetch function. Any invalidateQueries and reftchQueries will ignored. You will have to manually call the refetch function coming from useQuery when the query was created.

Source: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/disabling-queries